# Scaffolding Layout file for Identity in .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, scaffolding

When scaffolding Identity Pages for a .Net 6.0 project the Layout page does not get scaffolded.
I tried scaffolding via UI in Visual Studio, and via the command line:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --layout "/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" --force
```

Both don't generate a Layout file.
How can I scaffold the layout file?

Comment: For a workaround the source file is here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/testassets/Identity.DefaultUI.WebSite/Pages/_Layout.cshtml so just copy that. there's also a stylesheet for the sticky footer here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/testassets/Identity.DefaultUI.WebSite/wwwroot/css/site.css

Answer (score 0):

Just scaffold a page. You don't have to change it. I scaffolded in the Login page for example. `_Layout.cshtml` appears in the folder `\Pages\Shared`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Used to work that way, try a new .net 6 project (I'm using Blazor Server Side but don't think it makes a difference), the _Layout.cshtml doesn't get generated

Comment: @YStroli I did before I posted.

Comment: Weird, just retried and followed step by step your pics and doesn't generate. (also using 6.05, same libs referenced)

Comment: @YStroli Hrmm try Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design